# How to boot and repair Windows Vista with/without a boot disc?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, boot

Each time my laptop boots up it errors and says that a boot disc is required to repair it. I didnt get a disc with the laptop so i have burnt some that i downloaded onto a disc using an ISO burner and gone to repair it with that but still no joy. 
My windows is - windows vista home x32.

Im just clutching at straws really, hope you can help. :)

Comment: Download the Vista repair disc from here, burn the ISO as an image to a CD...http://www.mediafire.com/?zzzmyi0mmzr